# Trying to merge multiple reports in one

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I've tried to merge multiple reports into one without success, first I set the code to let the user enter the path where folder containing multiple reports is located, and then put the code to open all and copy and paste in a new one, but no success.. VBA is not able to recognize second part and open the files.

```
Sub files()
Dim folderpath As String
Dim FileOpen As String
Dim DialogBox As FileDialog
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim Filename As String

folderpath = InputBox("Please introduce the path where files are stored", "Select Files' Path", "Paste path here")
FileOpen = Dir(folderpath & "\*.xls*")
Do While Len(Filename) > 0
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileOpen)
wbk.Activate

Range(“A1”).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.Copy

Windows(“Book1”).Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim lr As Double
lr = wbk1.Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
Cells(lr + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
wbk.Close True
Filename = Dir
Loop

End Sub*
```

Comment: You're using `Workbooks.Open(FileOpen)` but the variable you're populating from `Dir()` just before `Loop` is `Filename`  You need to just use one of those variable names...  Also you have a bunch of "smart quotes" in your code - you need to change those to regular quotes.

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet in `wbk`? On one hand, `ThisWorkbook` is a reference to the workbook containing this code. On the other hand, you are using the generic `Book1` as a window name. Do you want to copy to `Sheet1` of `ThisWorkbook` or do you want to create a new workbook and copy to its `Sheet1`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for respond. I wanted to create a new workbook and copy the content of 4 different workbooks from another folder on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Worksheets' Ranges to a New Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReport()
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    sFolderPath = InputBox("Please introduce the path where files are stored", _
        "Select Files' Path", "Paste path here")
    If Len(sFolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    
    Dim sFilename As String: sFilename = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xls*")
    If Len(sFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sCount As Long
    
    Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFilename)
        On Error Resume Next ' test if the worksheet exists
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            sCount = sCount + 1
            If sCount = 1 Then ' with headers
                Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Else ' without headers
                With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                End With
            End If
            srg.Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count)
            Set sws = Nothing
        'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFilename = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Report created out of " & sCount & " worksheets.", _
        vbInformation, "CreateReport"

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUUUUCH!!!! It really helped me :D